# Why the names of the members, who opted for closure of my question, are not visible to me?

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions

My question - [Are Vaishnavism, Shaivism, etc., which encouraged sectarian attitude, contrary to Rig Vedic principles, therefore, anti-Hindu or anti-Sanatana Dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/42469/3869) was closed, with the following message, which is visible to me.

> Closed. **This question is opinion-based.** It is not currently accepting
> answers. Update the question so it can be answered with facts and
> citations. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the
> question or ***post a new one.***
>
> Closed 6 hours ago.
>
> (Private feedback for you)
>
> Edit question Delete question

I am posting screenshot hereunder.

[image]

---

Another question - [Was Vivekananda a proponent of birth-based caste-system or the guṇa-based?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/42419/3869), which was also closed, had the following message, which is visible to me.

> Closed. This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently
> accepting answers. Update the question so it focuses on one problem
> only. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the
> question.
>
> Closed 4 days ago by ***Rickross, YDS, Pandya♦.***
>
> (Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen votes
> privilege)
>
> Edit question

---

If we observe closely, we can find that in the case of my question, the names of the members, who opted for its closure, are not visible to me.

In the case of a question belongs to another member, the names of the members, who opted for its closure, are visible to me.

My question is, why the names of the members, who opted for  closure of my question, are not visible to me?

Comment: It is not just you. Even I can't see names of those who have voted to close my questions anymore. Seems like a new feature in SE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [a latest answer posted on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353004/380169), to the author of a post, the names of the users who voted to close that post, won't be shown any longer.

That's why you are not being able to see which users closed your question.

> The author actually no longer sees who voted to close their question
> in the post notice. They can still see them via the revision history
> or the timeline, though.

But, as indicated in that answer, you can still see the names of the users, through the revision link, provided your post was revised.

You can check this revision: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/42469/revisions

You can see the names then:

[image]

> Post Closed as "Opinion-based" by Carmen sandiego, Swami Vishwananda,
> TheLittleNaruto, Marcello Miorelli, idol worshipper

If your post was not revised even once, then I think you need to resort to the timeline of that post.

The timeline of your question is given in the following link, from where you can also view which users closed the question.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/42469/timeline

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information @Rickross

Comment: Just a clarification: the link to the revisions page exists for all posts even if they weren't edited. It's just that you will have to manually edit the URL to navigate to that page. See, for example [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/42513/revisions) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/42512/revisions).

Comment: Thanks .. @Brahadeesh

Answer (score 4):

[Carmen](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/why-the-names-of-the-members-who-opted-for-closure-of-my-question-are-not-visi/1966#comment9153_1964) and [Rickross](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1965/277) are right that it's due to recent feature change.

Orginally, it is the [New Post Notices rollout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/260388) feature announcement that was posted on MSE in Oct'19, followed by [Blog in August'19](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/08/20/upcoming-on-stack-overflow/).

Still the name of close voters were visible to post author. Yet another thread started for improving this feature and [it was suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/260388) to hide the name of close voters to the post authors, which has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by SE developers on [July 22](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/332502/revisions):

> Update: We've changed the post notices for question askers so that they do not see the usernames of close voters listed - this includes askers with the close/reopen vote privilege.